# foreign key constraint Error When deleting from Table in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Two Tables 
One table is Main Menu

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> SortOrder { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SpclWebSiteLink> SpclWebSiteLinks { get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<SubMenu> SubMenus { get; set; }
```

and other table have forgein key of Main Menu

```
public partial class LevelOneMenu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubMenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubMenu SubMenu { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LevelTwoMenu> LevelTwoMenus { get; set; }
}
```

and third Table have forgein key of Levelone Menu

```
public partial class LevelTwoMenu
{
    public LevelTwoMenu()
    {
        this.ProductMenus = new HashSet<ProductMenu>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LevelOneId { get; set; }    
    public virtual LevelOneMenu LevelOneMenu { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductMenu> ProductMenus { get; set; }
}
```

When i deleted from Main Menu Product Give forgein key Constrains Error because i have used main menu forgien key in LevelOne Table and Id of levelOne table used as forgien key in LevelTwo table. I want to delete Main product and other related row assign null values in the column but i am unable to understand this scenario. Can you guide me
Thanks in advance

Comment: which ORM framework are you using? Is it Entity Framework 6 or something else?

Comment: Check below ans for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework then you need to delete and re-adding EDMX again then it will work perfectly.

Before deleting EDMX try below steps for Updating EDMX if it works then no need to delete EDMX otherwise you have to delete and re-add EDMX again:

```html
-> Right Click on EDMX
-> Select Click Open
-> Right Click On Page
-> Select Update Model From Database EDMX
-> Save your changes
```

This will help you !!